# How to know which URL used which port in computer in cmd?

Tags: networking, cmd, port, ping

I am browsing few website on my browser like fb.com or google.com , How can i know which ports hosted these websites in my PC and on server.

I tried netstat command but i didn't show the result according to websites

```
netstat -a
netstat -an
```

Comment: you pretty much have a misconception of the relation between URLs, HTTP, TCP/IP and port numbers.

Comment: There's no port hosting Facebook's website on your computer, are you asking which port is being used on your PC to connect to Facebook?

Comment: yes, Which port is open while connected to fb ?

Comment: What if the question is really about the local port that is used to make the connection to the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, if using "HTTP://" the port is 80
If using "HTTPS://" the port is 443
You cannot change it without writing in the url, so they are unmodified

If any other port was being used, you'd have to access it using http://facebook.com:1234 or https://facebook.com:8443

Answer (score 0):

netstat will not give you information by the website. To get information by the website you need a proper L7 firewall.

Also - this question is much more relevant in SuperUser site and not SO.

Answer (score 0):

I had always used `netstat -an` as my 'go to' for quickly observing TCP port usage, not realising that I could get the URL of those foreign addresses simply by omitting the `n` option.

So to get the URLs of foreign addresses (instead of IPs), use:

```
netstat -aW
```

- `a` will show sockets used for server processes (optional)
- `W` makes sure the address isn't truncated i.e. it will ensure the whole URL is displayed

Comment: Not working....